# How to run Shredder Duplicate Finder (rmlint --gui) on Debian? ("Failed to load shredder: No module named 'shredder'")

Tags: debian, deduplication

I'd like to run the rmlint GUI (Shredder) on Debian10 but I get this error:

> Failed to load shredder: No module named 'shredder'
>   This might be due to a corrupted install; try reinstalling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the console run these two commands:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages  
rmlint --gui
```

Changing PYTHONPATH is also recommended in the software's documentation: https://rmlint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html#troubleshooting
In this answer (see above) it's explained how to change it.

If you don't want to run this every time to start the application you could add `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` to the bottom of the ~/.bashrc file so that you only need to start the app with `rmlint --gui`. However, this might cause other python applications to crash.

**If you want the app to start from its app shortcut with the blue icon** (e.g. via the search results or the pinned shortcut) right click it and select Edit Application... then go the the Application tab and replace Command with the following:

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages && rmlint --gui`
Now you can start the app by clicking on its shortcut.

---

Edit: `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/python*` could help if you have installed python3 wrong somehow (it should remain installed via your package manager). You could get this error if this applies to you:

```
Failed to load shredder: cannot import name '_gi' from 'gi' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
This might be due to a corrupted install; try reinstalling.
```